# How to add single quote " ' "at beginning and end of an 5 pos integer

Tags: textpad

I need to add a single quote at the begining and end to a 5 position integer field in TextPad.

Ex:

```
14982
14983
14985
14991
14995
15019
```

Desired result:

```
'14982',
'14983',
'14985',
'14991',
'14995',
'15019'
```

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>F1</kbd>, the Textpad help provides a very useful hint with examples:

1. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Text to find: `^.*?$`
3. Replace with: `'$0',`
4. Check the "Regular expressions" check-box
5. Click "Replace All" button.

Wala!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [search-and-replace function](http://johnbokma.com/textpad/textpad-reference.pdf):

1. Check the regex box
2. Use `\(\d\d\d\d\d\)`  as the source (you can also use `\(\d{5}\)` )—space at the end
3. Use `'\1',`  as the target (again a space at the end)
4. Replace all
5. Delete the extraneous `,`  at the end of the line(s):

   - Manually if there’s a few
   - Using regular expressions if there’s a lot:

     1. Check the regex box
     2. Use `, $` as the source
     3. Use an empty field for the replacement text
     4. Replace all

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\(\<[0-9]\{5\}\>\)` (words consisting of exactly five digits) with `'\1'`, and then `' '` with `', '`.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:
1.For the first "'" (single quote), put ^ on Find What text box and ' on the Replace with text box.
2. for the second "'" (single quote) and  ", " , put $ on Find What text box and ' , on the Replace with text box.
'D4881',
'D2243',
'G7051',
'X9767',
'D3040',

Answer (score 0):

Enter ^ in the 'Find what' and ' in the 'Replace with' and Regular expression selected

Enter $ in the 'Find what' and ', in the 'Replace with' and Regular expression selected

Comment: Please explain how this answer is better than the [answer](http://superuser.com/a/558430) posted by Sarah Cao?

Answer (score -1):

Easier solution

- Find What:     `(\d{5})`
- Replace with:  `'\1',`
- Regular Expresion: `<checked>`
- Replace all

Answer (score -1):

This worked well for me:

Find: (.+)[ \t]+(.+)[ \t]+(.+)$
Replace: '\1','\2',\3'

Comment: Can you explain what this does?